# rhcs fence_node error

Tags: linux, centos, cluster, кластеризация

Вряд ли кто-то сталкивался с этим, но мало ли...
Есть у меня **red hat cluster suite** состоящий из 2-ух вируальных нод и их гипервизора KVM (Примерно [это](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/293183) но "KVM host" один). Везде centos 6.9 . Кластер собран верно, cluster.conf везде идентичны, состояние кластера консистентное. Пытаюсь настроить fence_xvm. На гипервизоре установлен fence_virtd и настроен тоже верно. Команда, например, `fence_xvm -a 225.0.0.12 -k /etc/cluster/fence_xvm.key -H node1 -o status` выдаёт корректный результат `Status: ON` . Но команда `fence_node node1 -vv` выдаёт ошибку

```
fence node1 dev 0.0 agent fence_xvm result: error from agent
agent args: nodename=node1 agent=fence_xvm key_file=/etc/cluster/fence_xvm.key multicast_address=225.0.0.12 
fence node1 failed
```

В логах:

```
Apr  7 20:16:17 node1 fence_node[8848]: fence node1 failed
Apr  7 21:04:25 node1 fence_xvm[24556]: No domain specified
```

При выполнении `fence_node node1 -vv` tcpdump'ом трафика я не вижу ни на node1 , ни на супервизоре, в отличии от `fence_xvm` .

Похожая проблема описана [тут](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/668673) , там ребята рекомендовали вырубить selinux, я это сделал но ничего не помогло. В общем я в отчаянии: ничего не могу нагуглить и ничего не понимаю. Может у кого-то есть какие-нибудь идеи? :(

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, надо в `fencedevice` передавать `port` что есть замена устаревшего `domain` , либо в `fence` отдавать его через `method` .

```
<fencedevice agent="fence_xvm" name="virtfence1" key_file="/etc/cluster/fence_xvm_host1.key" multicast_address="225.0.1.12" port="node1"/>
```

Актуальную инфу удалось найти в дебаггинге, который просто выдаёт актуальный ман в xml-формате: `ccs -d -h node_name --lsfenceinst`